# How to Prevent Custom box Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am using Custombox modal plugin for good effects. I initialized the plugin using the following links

```
<link href="assets/libs/custombox/custombox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/libs/custombox/custombox.min.js"></script>
```

and I have created a modal. Everything is working fine but when I am trying to add

> data-backdrop = 'static'

and

> data-keyboard  = 'false'

are not working. What's wrong with the custom modal box. When I use basic Bootstrap modal backdrop and keyboard data attributes are working well.

button code

```
<a href="#edit-profile" class="btn btn-dark waves-effect waves-light btn-edit" data-animation="slidetogether" data-plugin="custommodal" data-overlaySpeed="100" data-overlayColor="#36404a" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">edit</a>
```

Modal code

```
<div id="edit-profile" class="modal-demo" >
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="Custombox.modal.close();">
      <span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="custom-modal-title">Profile</h4>
    <div class="custom-modal-text">      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this option to your modal

```
new Custombox.modal({
  // Options
  content: {
    close: false,
  },
  overlay: {
    close: false,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After adding this to my script it showing **Invalid shorthand property initializer**

Comment: change `=` to `:`

Comment: `new Custombox.modal({
  // Options
  content : {
    close: false,
  },
  overlay : {
    close: false,
  }
});` added this but no use

Comment: do not added all that code, you only need to add options `content: {close: false,},overlay: {close: false,}` to your modal you haved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209995/discussion-between-nelson-feel-and-iamhuynq).

Comment: check chat room @nelsonfeel

Comment: https://codepen.io/07f3b5cb-7b5d-437c-a397-a90beac2c33d/pen/JjdBLor